# Accessibility issue on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

```js
$("#onReviewClick").click(function()
{ $('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: ($("#scrollHere").offset().top)-100 },
1000); });
```

I have a text read more, this onclick scrolls down to the footer part of the page and focus on the reviews. I want the screen reader to read the reviews when the scroll moves down to the review part.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using for your `onclick` event?

Comment: $("#onReviewClick").click(function() {
              $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: ($("#scrollHere").offset().top)-100
              }, 1000);
          });

Comment: can you provide the working in https://stackblitz.com/, for ease?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `animate` callback function to run your code after the animation has completed.

Then I believe you add the `aria-live="polite"` attribute to the element you want your screen reader to speak.

```
$("#onReviewClick").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($("#scrollHere").offset().top) - 100
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $("#scrollHere").attr('aria-live', 'polite');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it didn't work. Can you please  provide some other way

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. Your HTML, details about how you're using a screen reader, what you tried, what didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and safest way to scroll the screen and make the screen reader to go read at the correct place is to use good old anchors as the base:

```
<a href="#more">More</a>
.
.
.
<p id="more">More text</p>
```

Slightly less simple and safe, but still very well working, is to **immediately** put the focus at an element naturally focusable or made focusable with tabindex=-1:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('more').focus();">More</a>
.
.
.
<p id="more" tabindex="-1">More text</p>
```

I emphasize about the word **immediately** because moving the focus outside of an immediate interaction can sometimes cause problems. It may be totally ignored, or make the screen reader to jump in another place in between and then don't follow the second focus change a few milliseconds later.
So, doing it at the end of an animation, even if it's only a few dozends of milliseconds, can cause problems.

This answer won't make designers happy, but ideally, you should take the ancohr or immediate focus pattern as a base, and then build your animation on top of that if you can, rather than the opposite. Accessibility speaking, it's going to be much more robust. By the way, note that the user can have configured his device to disable animations or reduce them, and you should take that into account, too.